# adding via Python to Docker MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb

I'm trying to add some data to MongoDB in consumer.py file (the json is sent from producer.py via rabbitmq)

It produces the JSON, However after I added MongoDB connection and couple lines of code (look below) it doesn't add them to DB, moreover it doesn't print that it got the message at all.

here is the code:

```
myclient = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")
db = myclient.database_sample
my_collection = db["database"]


def receive_msg(ch, method, properties, body):
    """function to receive the message from rabbitmq
    print it
    sleep for 2 seconds
    ack the message"""

    print('received msg : ', body.decode('utf-8'))
    time.sleep(2)
    print('acking it')
    ch.basic_ack(delivery_tag=method.delivery_tag)
    data = json.loads(body)
    my_collection.insert_one(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
myclient = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")
db = myclient["database_sample"]
my_collection = db["database"]


def receive_msg(ch, method, properties, body):
    """function to receive the message from rabbitmq
    print it
    sleep for 2 seconds
    ack the message"""

    print('received msg : ', body.decode('utf-8'))
    time.sleep(2)
    print('acking it')
    ch.basic_ack(delivery_tag=method.delivery_tag)
    data = json.loads(body)
    insertedMessage = my_collection.insert_one(data)
```

I can't think of any other issue, other than perhaps your body being an invalid JSON string.

I hope that helped:)

Comment: I made another edit. Is database_sample the name of your database? I think the issue was with your connection in the first few lines.

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work.
it works in a script with local mongoDB instead of docker one tho so I doubt it's because of wrong JSON, probably I messed something up with MongoDB, maybe wrong host or something with docker? but I have no clue. Oh and the db creates, but it's empty without any collections etc.

Comment: Alright, well unfortunately there's not much I can do there to help. You could take a look at the official documentation here: https://www.mongodb.com/basics/create-database
Sorry I couldn't be of help:/
Good luck!

Comment: Okay never mind, I just found out in logs that the docker just doesn't download the Pymongo, kinda hard to spot that.